# How can I determine if an iscsi device is a mounted Linux filesystem?

Tags: linux, iscsi

EDIT:
This is on a Debian 7 sytstem (more accurately Proxmox hypervisor https://www.proxmox.com/en/) 2.6.32-48-pve kernel.

I have a disk partition as an iscsi target on my backend infiniband storage. I've mounted the target locally on the initiator (on `/mnt/iscsi`). If I need to reboot the initiator, I need to unmount `/mnt/iscsi` and then logout of the portal prior to rebooting (at least it was this way a couple years ago. been a while since I've worked with iscsi).

How can I determine which filesystems are mounted over iscsi? The regular `mount` command just displays the block device which was created by the initiator eg: `/dev/sdc`.

```
/dev/sdc on /mnt/iscsi type ext4 (rw,relatime,barrier=1,data=ordered)
```

I'd like to automate the unmount/logout prior to a reboot but this information is not enough to determine if the filesystem in question needs to be run through `iscsiadm ... --logout` after unmounting.

Comment: Can you provide information on the actual Linux distribution and version in use?

Comment: Good idea. Added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `iscsiadm -m session -P 3` and check the last section "Attached SCSI devices"

Just FYI: If you set `iscsid` to start on boot you do not need to unmount/logout iSCSI partitions prior to reboot. As long as the partition is in /etc/fstab and has a `_netdev` option.

Comment: Thanks for the `iscsid` info. The daemon is running, however I don't see an init script for it. This is a vended product built on Debian 7 so they may have made some customizations in regards to iscsi initialization.

Comment: If it were for RHEL or CentOS, the `netfs` service handles this.

Comment: `iscsiadm -m session -P 3` works as noted to show device in use by target. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
iscsiadm -m session -P 3 | grep 'Target\|disk'
```

The iscsiadm utility is a command-line tool allowing discovery and login to iSCSI targets, as well as access and management of the open-iscsi database.

`-m, --mode op` specifies the mode. `op` must be one of `discoverydb`, `node`, `fw`, `host iface` or `session`. This command will list the sessions targets (and grep within the result).